# How to write expression in <s:textfield value" ">

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl, valuestack, struts-tags

Hello friend I am trying to write Decryption value expression into s:textfield value"<%=custFirstName%>" something like this but it give me an error i.e  According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions so what is the alternate way to do same thing in . Please help me out. in INPUT type its working well but i want to do it same thing through struts tage.

This is my code

```
    <s:iterator value="userList">
        <s:set var="custFirstName" value="custFirstname"/>
        <s:set var="custLastName" value="custLastname"/>
        <s:set var="custEmail" value="custEmail"/>
        <s:set var="custPhone" value="custPhone"/>
        <s:set name="custVerified" value="custIsVerified"/>
        <%
        String custFirstName = pageContext.getAttribute("custFirstName").toString();
        String custLastName = pageContext.getAttribute("custLastName").toString();
        String custEmail = pageContext.getAttribute("custEmail").toString();
        String custPhone = pageContext.getAttribute("custPhone").toString();

        Encryption encryption=new Encryption();
        custFirstName = Encryption.decString(custFirstName);
        custLastName = Encryption.decString(custLastName);
        custEmail = Encryption.decString(custEmail);
        custPhone = Encryption.decString(custPhone);
    %>




            <td> <s:textfield value="<%=custFirstName%>" label="First Name"/></td>
            <%-- <input type="text" value="<%=custFirstName%>" > --%>
            <td> <s:textfield name="custLastName" label="Last Name"/></td>
            <td> <s:textfield name="custEmail" label="Email"/></td>
            <td> <s:textfield name="custPhone" label="phone"/></td>
            <td> <s:textfield name="custCountry" label="Country"/></td>
            <td> <s:textfield name="custState" label="State"/></td>
            <td> <s:textfield name="custCity" label="City"/></td>
            <s:submit value="Update"></s:submit>

    </s:iterator>   

</s:form>



<input type="text "value="<%=custFirstName%>">
```

and I want to write above input value expression into s:textfield value="" how I can do it.

Comment: <%=custFirstName%> is this a scriplet value...??

Comment: scriptlets discouraged in JSP and not allowed in struts tags. You should use a better approach. Why do you need to write a business logic into JSP?

Comment: I know its not a good approach but I want to decrypt a value that's y I am using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
<td> <s:textfield value="%{#custFirstName}" label="First Name"/></td>
```

Comment: I used this also but it shows me Encrypted value not decrypted value

Comment: Bring your c:set tag after you decrypt the values so they reflect decrypted values rather than encrypted ones.

Comment: Did you use `<s:set var="custFirstName"><%=custFirstName%></s:set>` after descrypting? If not do this and its the right way of assigning the value.

Comment: Yes it was a valid question and good thing was it was formatted and well explained. So +1.

Answer (score 0):

You needed to set the value attribute, that's right, but it should be OGNL expression.

```
Encryption encryption=new Encryption();
custFirstName = Encryption.decString(custFirstName);
custLastName = Encryption.decString(custLastName);
custEmail = Encryption.decString(custEmail);
custPhone = Encryption.decString(custPhone);
ValueStack vs = ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack();
vs.set("custFirstName", custFirstName);
vs.set("custLastName", custLastName);
vs.set("custEmail", custEmail);
vs.set("custPhone", custPhone);
```

and then you can use OGNL

```
<s:textfield name="custFirstName" value="%{#custFirstName}" label="First Name"/>

...
```

You might also look this [Struts 2 Value Stack/OGNL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_value_stack_ognl.htm).

Comment: No its not working its shows me Encrypted value not decrypted value

Comment: I don't know what this `Encryption` class is doing, but the values decrypted or not are *shown* on JSP in textfields.